# How do i mock a another method which is called in controller action?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

Here I have one scenario in which i have to call another function in my controller action for some input purpose.
as below.

```
public IActionResult Dashboard()
        {
            try
            {
                    var allStuds = repository.GetAllStudentss();
                    var result = getFirstClassResult(allStuds);
                    return View("Dashboard", result );                         
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {             
                return View();
            }
        }


 public List<DashboardViewModel> getFirstClassResult(List<DashboardViewModel> model)
        {
      return students.OrderByDescending(x=>x.ExamDate).ToList();
    }
```

here is code inside my tets case.

```
var controller = new StudentController(repositoryMock.Object, null, sessionManagerMock.Object);
    var date = new DateTime();
    var model= new List<DashboardViewModel>          
    controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = GetHttpContext(CreateSessionMock(true), authenticationServiceMock);
    controller.TempData = new TempDataDictionary(controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext, Mock.Of<ITempDataProvider>());
    controller.Url = GetUrlHelper();
    contextMock.Setup(mock => mock.GetAllStudents()).Returns(model);
    var repository = new StudentRepository(factoryMock.Object);
    var res = repository.GetAllStudents();                
    var result = controller.Dashboard() as ViewResult;
    Assert.Equal("Dashboard", result.ViewName);
```

and here i am writting test case in which I have to mock `getFirstClassResult(allStuds)` method.
which am unable to do.

Comment: Generally you can´t mock a non-virtual member, as mocking just creates a type deriving from your mocked one. But how should it create an override for something you can´t override? It´s not possible. Apart from this "I am unable to do so" isn´t a proper problem-description. Please elaborate what you´ve tried exactly and what you get as result.

Comment: Furthermore you usually shouldn´t mock the system under test, that is the class you want to test.

Comment: ok,
but what if i want to write the test case for the above mentioned scenario?

Comment: Well, I can´t see much of a scenario. However it seems you don´t want to mock your `getFirstClassResult`-method but the database-layer which means the `repository.GetAllStudents`-method in your case. Why not simply mock this inetad to return only a few students?

Answer (score 0):

The following line is killing everything and introducing an impossible to unit test in isolation strong coupling between your controller and data access layer:

```
IUserRepository repo = new UserRepository();
```

Absolutely never write anything like this in any application (not only ASP.NET MVC). if you write code like this it will always break in your unit test and you will not be able to test it.

This is impossible to mock/unit test.

You should use constructor injection to weaken coupling between your layers:

```
public class UserController : Controller{
private readonly IUserRepository _repos;
public UserController(IUserRepository repo)
{
    _repos = repo;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Details");
}

public ActionResult Details()
{
    IQueryable<Business.Entities.User> users = _repos.GetAll();
    return View("Details", users);
}}
```

Now you can unit test in isolation by mocking:

```
   [Test]
   public void Details()
   {
Mock<IUserRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
mockRepo.Setup(ur => ur.GetAll()).Returns(MockedGetAll());
var v = mockRepo.Object.GetAll();

var controller = new UserController(mockRepo.Object);
var result = controller.List() as ViewResult;
var model = result.ViewData.Model as IQueryable<User>;

Assert.AreEqual("List", result.ViewName);
Assert.IsNotNull(model);
Assert.Greater(model.Count(), 0);}
```

Obviously because now your controller depends on this repository you could use a DI framework to configure your dependencies.

People that don't want to use DI framework often write code like this and provide 2 constructors (one for unit testing and one for the real application):

```
private readonly IUserRepository _repo;
public UserController(IUserRepository repo)
{
_repo = repo;
 }
 public UserController(): this(new UserRepository())
 {}
```

Also Refer This For
[religion of dependency injection](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/20/the-religion-of-dependency-injection/)